# С помощью регулярных выражений определить корректность введенных паролей

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения

Задание: "С помощью регулярных выражений определить корректность введенных паролей. Требования для паролей: пароль должен содержать только буквы латинского алфавита (строчный или прописные) и цифры. Пробелы, подчеркивания и другие знаки препинания не допускаются".

Я написал функцию, которая проверяет пароли на корректность с помощью регулярок, однако она не учитывает условие, что цифры должны быть обязательно. Я пока только начинаю разбираться с регулярными выражениями, поэтому не до конца понимаю, как исправить свою ошибку. Буду очень признателен за помощь в решении.

```
//проверка паролей с помощью регулярного выражения
std::vector<bool> regexp(const std::vector<std::string> password) {
    std::vector<bool> correct(password.size());
    std::regex e("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");

    for (size_t i = 0; i < password.size(); ++i) {
        correct[i] = std::regex_search(password[i], e);
    }

    return correct;
}
```

Comment: Проще *(и намного эффективней (а также всем понятней (возможно это главное)))* в цикле подсчитать количество букв (`isalpha()`) и цифр (`isdigit()`) и проверить в одном if-е. `if (n_alpha && n_digits && n_alpha + n_digits == password.size()) // good passwd, have alpha and digits, but no more`

Answer (score 1):

Ну... можно так:

```
std::vector<bool> regexp(const std::vector<std::string>& password) {
    std::vector<bool> correct(password.size());
    static std::regex e("[a-zA-Z]*[0-9][0-9a-zA-Z]*");

    for (size_t i = 0; i < password.size(); ++i) {
        correct[i] = std::regex_match(password[i],e);
    }
    return correct;
}
```

Правда, одни только цифры - допустимый пароль. Но вы ведь требовали в обязательном порядке только цифры, но не буквы?...

P.S. Допускаю наличие куда более короткого и красивого решения, но что-то сразу в голову не приходит.

P.P.S. Спасибо Fat-Zer за подправленный ответ.

Comment: перемудрил малость... `[0-9a-zA-Z]*[0-9][0-9a-zA-Z]*` будет достаточно... или даже `[a-zA-Z]*[0-9][0-9a-zA-Z]*`

Comment: Не работает. Учитываются подчеркивания и другие знаки препинания. UPD: все работает. когда пытался поправить самостоятельно, поменял regex_match на regex_search. Огромное спасибо!!!!!

Comment: @Fat-Zer Спасибо! Я и написал, что явно должно быть куда лучшее решение. Я этим инструментом, увы, редко пользуюсь...